# UIPopoverController & navigate to UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I am developing app for iPad. I am able to display UIPopoverController with tableView with some list in VIEW1.

I want to navigate from VIEW1 to VIEW2 when user select a row from table.

In other words,

1. VIEW1 contains a button1.
2. When user presses button1, then Popover displayed on VIEW1.
3. In popover, there is a table with some rows. (VIEW1)
4. When user select a row then it should call VIEW2 i.e navigate from VIEW1 to VIEW2.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: VIEW1 is a bit confusing to me ... It has a button and then it's in the popover as a table view??

Comment: What issue are you facing here??

Comment: Sounds like just using a `UITableViewController` as `contentViewController` in `UIPopoverController`... What did you try, what doesn't work?

Comment: do you want to open the new view on  tableview rowclick on popover?

Comment: 1st solution: Check the did select method of tableview.

Comment: 2nd solution: U must had set view to popviewcontroller. u had set View1, U should change it to view2 when user taps on cell of a table.

Answer (score 1):

In tableview delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can call method as follows:

1.While initializing popover controller define target and selector as follows:
 [theController setTarget:self andSelector:@selector(yourMethod:)];

2.and In view controller which contains tableview, you can define setTarget method as follows:

```
-(void)setTarget:(id)inTarget andSelector:(SEL)inSelector {
    mTarget = inTarget;
    m_Selector = inSelector;
}
```

where mTarget is of id type and mSelector is selector.

3.Then didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can call yourMethod as follows:

```
if ([m_Target respondsToSelector:m_Selector]) {
        [m_Target performSelector:m_Selector withObject:nil];
    }
```

And if table view is in same view then you can call yourMethod in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

In the table views controller file you'll want to use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to present view2, e.g:

```
[self presentViewController:view2controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Just add UITableViewController to UIPopOverController to navigate from VIEW1 to VIEW2.

Thanks for your efforts. Below is the code.

```
        tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        tableViewController.tableView = tblView;
        tableViewController.tableView.delegate = self;
        tableViewController.tableView.dataSource = self;
        UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tableViewController];
        self.popoverController = popover;
        popoverController.delegate = self;

        [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(442.0f, 527.0f)];
        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(bkBtn.frame.origin.x+bkBtn.frame.size.width/2, bkBtn.frame.origin.y, 442.0f, 527.0f) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];

        [tableViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
VIEW2 *view2=[[VIEW2 alloc]initWithName:@"VIEW2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
[view2 release];
}
just try it.This will help you.
```